# Android login via Google Sign-In with a Spring Boot backend

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, google-signin, spring-security-oauth2

As the title says, I'm trying to use the Google Sign-In API with a Spring Boot backend server, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).

Just to describe the context, the Spring backend is basically a resource+authentication server, that is currently providing Oauth2 authentication to a second spring boot application containing the frontend website, via Google SSO or simple form login (similar to what's described [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver)).

My original idea was to mimic the *@EnableOauth2Sso* annotation by simply providing an access token to the android app and attach it to every request as "Bearer ".
Using the user credentials for this was pretty straightforward: I simply make a request to the server at "/oauth/token", using those credentials inserted by the user as authentication and I correctly receive the access token.

Now, I have absolutely no idea on how to build a similar procedure with the Google API in Android. The tutorial page I linked before describes how to get a token ID and how the server should validate it, but **after that** I don't know what to do.

So far I've managed to add a filter to the security chain that simply checks the token like this:

```
    private Authentication attemptOpenIDAuthentication(@NonNull String tokenString){
        String clientId = authServices.getClientId();
        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, factory)
        .setAudience(Arrays.asList(clientId, androidClient))
        .build();

        try {
            GoogleIdToken token = verifier.verify(tokenString);
            if (token != null) {
                return authServices.loadAuthentication(token.getPayload());
            } else {
                throw new InvalidTokenException("ID token is null");
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not validate ID token");
        }
    }
```

This manages indeed to create an Authentication object, but **how can I generate an access token after the authentication filtering?**

To recap, so far I've got:

1. The Android app successfully retrieves the Google token ID and sends it to the server
2. The server sucessfully intercepts the request and validates the token

I'm basically missing the third point where I return a proper access token to the Android client.
Here you are a simple scheme to better understand the situation:
[image: Crappy scheme of the problem. Web frontend is working great, android is missing Google login.]

Is there any other way to validate the token **and** get an access token from the server, or should I completely change the authentication procedure on Android?

Comment: Hi. Could you tell me? Have you done this task?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Yes I did, unfortunately this was an old university project and I do not have the source code at hand anymore. However I can briefly explain how I ended up solving this: on the android App use the Google SDK, this returns a token that you can send to a custom token granter to a Spring backend (see [here for example](https://github.com/galcyurio/tut-spring-security-oauth2-jwt-custom-token-granter). Basically you send the SDK token to the custom oauth2 endpoint and validate it through the standard Google APIs in order to return a token or deny it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell: Yes, you need an access token from the server. If I understand this correctly, a webapp is already authenticated via Oauth on your backend, so the procedure is similar here: Load the user with the google-ID and generate a token. In my application I used a JWT which is valid for 30 days. If the token expires, the Google authentication in the app is usually still valid, so the token can be renewed using the Google ID. With Oauth you can also send a refresh-token directly. 
It is important that the app always checks the Google authentication first and only in a second step that of the backend.

For the Authentication process on the backend u may need to manually implement a dedicated securityConfiguration for this. Have a look at the jhipster project, they implemented a custom jwt-authentication which may give you an idea how it works.